# Changing the arrow tip size in sankey diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, sankey

I'm using the `sankey` package to create [Sankey diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram). When using the `arrow` start and end styles for Sankey nodes, the arrow tips extend, by default, by `10pt`.

Looking at the [package documentation](https://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/contrib/sankey/sankey.pdf) (version 3.0.1; section 5.4, p. 21), this appears to be a hard-coded value. Thus my question is: what's the best way of making this configurable so that the depth (as it were) of arrow tips can be conveniently changed as diagrams are drawn?

Here is a small sample document to play around with (thanks Alan Munn for the suggestion):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sankey}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{sankeydiagram}
\sankeyset{start style=arrow, end style=arrow}
\sankeynodestart{at={0, 0}, name=q0, quantity=5}
\sankeynodestart{at={0, -2}, name=q1, quantity=25}
\sankeyadvance{q0}{2cm}
\sankeyend{q0}
\sankeyadvance{q1}{2cm}
\sankeyend{q1}
\end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Full disclosure: since the `sankey` package was started in response to a question on tex.sx, it is my hope that this question too will lead to further development and a new version of that package where the value isn't hard-coded anymore. But in the meantime, I appreciate your answers!)

Comment: It would be helpful to add a small example document that people could play with.

Comment: You're right, of course. I'll add one in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `arrow` style is just a predefined style. You can define your own style.

To define the new style `arrow 20`:

```
\sankeyset{
  new start style={arrow 20}{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-20pt,0) -- ([xshift=-20pt/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-20pt]\name.right) -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-20pt,0) -- ([xshift=-20pt/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-20pt]\name.right) -- (\name.right)
  },
  new end style={arrow 20}{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=20pt]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=20pt]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right)
  },
}
```

To use it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sankey}

\sankeyset{
  new start style={arrow 20}{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-20pt,0) -- ([xshift=-20pt/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-20pt]\name.right) -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-20pt,0) -- ([xshift=-20pt/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-20pt]\name.right) -- (\name.right)
  },
  new end style={arrow 20}{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=20pt]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=20pt]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right)
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{sankeydiagram}
\sankeyset{start style=arrow 20, end style=arrow 20}
\sankeynodestart{at={0, 0}, name=q0, quantity=5}
\sankeynodestart{at={0, -2}, name=q1, quantity=25}
\sankeyadvance{q0}{2cm}
\sankeyend{q0}
\sankeyadvance{q1}{2cm}
\sankeyend{q1}
\end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Variable length

Your new style can use a macro as parameter.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{sankey}

\sankeyset{
  new start style={variable arrow}{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-\arrowvariabledist,0) -- ([xshift=-\arrowvariabledist/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-\arrowvariabledist]\name.right) -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ++(-\arrowvariabledist,0) -- ([xshift=-\arrowvariabledist/6]\name.center)
    -- ([xshift=-\arrowvariabledist]\name.right) -- (\name.right)
  },
  new end style={variable arrow}{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=\arrowvariabledist]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right) -- cycle
  }{
    (\name.left) -- ([yshift=1mm]\name.left)
    -- ([xshift=\arrowvariabledist]\name.center) -- ([yshift=-1mm]\name.right)
    -- (\name.right)
  },
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{sankeydiagram}
    \sankeyset{start style=variable arrow, end style=variable arrow}
    
    \def\arrowvariabledist{30pt}
    \sankeynodestart{at={0, 0}, name=q0, quantity=5}
    \sankeyadvance{q0}{2cm}
    \sankeyend{q0}
    
    \def\arrowvariabledist{20pt}
    \sankeynodestart{at={0, -2}, name=q1, quantity=25}
    \sankeyadvance{q1}{2cm}
    \sankeyend{q1}
  \end{sankeydiagram}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that's a possibility, though I'd then have to define a new style anytime I want to change the depth of an arrow tip.

Comment: @chsk In your own style, you can use a macro instead of the hard-coded `20pt` value.